# How can I use closures to invoke methods by name with various signatures and return types

Tags: closures, swift

I have been fighting with the type hierarchy in Swift. I got all sort of runtime exceptions and compile errors trying to do something that took me a few minutes to write in Python. At one point, I got XCode 6 to throw exceptions in the linker and lock my machine trashing and indexing like mad. At this point, I am turning to the community to seek some help.

Basically I am hoping I can set a generic dispatcher to call methods by names. Here is a the skeleton for the code I am trying to run:

```
class CallbackDemo {

    var interface: CallbackInterface = CallbackInterface()

    func getString() -> String { return "0.1" }
    func getInt() -> Int { return 1 }
    func getIntMul(factor: Int) -> Int { return 2*factor }
    func getVoid() {}

    init() {
        interface.callbacks = [ "getString": getString,
            "getVoid": getVoid,
            "getInt": getInt,
            "getMul": {(factor:Int) -> Int in return factor * 10 }
        ]

        if let result = self.interface.call("getString") {
            println("%s", result)
        }

    }
}

class CallbackInterface {
    typealias GenericSignature = (Any...) -> Any?

    var callbacks: Dictionary<String, GenericSignature> = [:]

    func call(name: String, params: Any...) -> Any? {
        if let cb = callbacks[name] {
            return cb(params)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

The program doesn't compile (as I said, the one that does crashes the linker). However this snippet of code represents what I am hoping I can achieve: registering generic signatures, calling them with the name associated with them and returning something (or nothing).

AnyObject apparently doesn't cut it as I am also returning Int. Another problem I have with methods that don't pass params is that (Any?...) is hoping to get at least one param. Would that be the self first param it is referring to? I have no clue. I was under the impression that variadics can take no params, which works on standalone but for some unknown reasons (at least to me) doesn't work in this context.

I hope someone can shade some light on this. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Try having your functions return an optional.  The compiler may be having problems with converting hard types to Any?

Comment: Also: println("%s", result) => println("\(result)") ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function signatures don't match, try:

```
func getString(args:Any...) -> String? { return "0.1" }
func getInt(args:Any...) -> Int? { return 1 }
func getIntMul(args:Any...) -> Int? { return 2*(args[0] as Int) }
func getVoid(args:Any...) {}

init() {
    interface.callbacks = [
        "getString": getString,
        "getVoid": getVoid,
        "getInt": getInt,
        "getMul": {(args:Any...) -> Int? in return (args[0] as Int) * 10 }
    ]

    if let result = self.interface.call("getString") {
        println("%s", result)
    }

}
```

Essentially the function signatures you're using now indicate that 0 or 1 single arguments are going to be passed, but your typealias indicates that an array will be passed, so there's a mismatch and the compiler gets unhappy.

I also tried leaving the func returns as non-optionals, but the playground was crashing on that.  I think it should probably be ok in the long run, but the playground and/or compiler have many issues still.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You clarified something that I wasn't aware about variadics simply for the fact that you can call a variadic method with no arguments. I modified my code to overload the calls with an argument array. Since splatting is not supported yet by Swift, this is providing me a workaround for the time being. For a language that's built on the shoulders of objc, I find it very difficult to do stuff that was so easy to realize with the ancient language. Hopefully Apple is listening and will improve Swift shortcomings over time.